# Basic contour integration

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I am trying to evaluate $$\int_{\gamma(0;2)}\frac {e^{i\pi z/2}}{z^2-1}\, \mathrm d z$$ using the Cauchy integral formula

The problem is it is not holomorphic at $1$ and $-1$. My textbook suggests partial fractions, but surely the issue still exists?

Comment: The function is perfectly holomorphic along $\gamma(0;2)$.

Comment: What is $\gamma(0;2)$?

Comment: Yes my textbook uses slightly weird notation - It's the disc centred on 0 with radius 2 (I hope!)

Comment: I don't think $\gamma(0;2)$ is a *disc*, but rather the boundary of the disc, i.e. the *circle* $|z|=2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(z)=\frac{e^{i\pi z/2}}{z^2-1} $ is a meromorphic function with simple poles at $z=\pm 1$, having residues:

$$ \text{Res}\left(f(z),z=\pm 1\right) = \lim_{z\to \pm 1}\frac{e^{i\pi z/2}}{z\pm 1}=\frac{i}{2}, $$
so, by the residue theorem:
$$ \oint_{\|z\|=2} f(z)\,dz = 2\pi i\left(\frac{i}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)=\color{red}{-2\pi}.$$

Comment: Thanks- I am trying to do it with the cauchy integral formula though. Is it possible with partial fractions?

Comment: @bwv869: the first line is equivalent to $\frac{1}{z^2-1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{1}{z+1}\right)$ and the residue theorem is a consequence of Cauchy's integral formula.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$
\frac1{z^2-1}=\frac12\left(\frac1{z-1}-\frac1{z+1}\right)
$$
using partial fractions, we can compute the integral as
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{\gamma(0;2)}\frac{e^{i\pi z/2}}{z^2-1}\,\mathrm{d}z
&=\frac12\int_{\gamma(0;2)}\frac{e^{i\pi z/2}}{z-1}\,\mathrm{d}z
-\frac12\int_{\gamma(0;2)}\frac{e^{i\pi z/2}}{z+1}\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&=\pi ie^{i\pi/2}-\pi ie^{-i\pi/2}\\[9pt]
&=-2\pi
\end{align}
$$
but we still need to use residues as in Jack's answer.

Comment: Not sure if you have the book, it's Introduction to Complex Analysis by Hilary Priestley. Anyway she uses the Cauchy integral formula on those two integrals, and ends up with $1/2 e^{i \pi /2} - 1/2 e^{-i \pi /2}$. I think she might have forgotten the 2 pi i factor though

Comment: I don't have that book, but indeed, there appears to be a factor of $2\pi i$ missing.

Comment: I have the book, and I can confirm that there is a $i2\pi$ missing (it is example 13.2 by the way).